# Read a file in Qt as it is being Written

Tags: bash, qt

I am writing the output of a bash command in a file. In Qt, I want to read this file, as it is being written to. The command writes the output gradually. How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monitor file changes with [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class

Comment: This class will just tell me whether the file has changed or not. I want to read the output. The problem here is that the other process is still writing the file. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What about using a regular QFile to read the new file content ?